# htaccess 301 redirect doesnt work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

HTACCESS for 301 redirect:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 Redirect 301 /page.asp?DH=35 http://www.domain.ch/karriere
```

HTACCESS Code (later in the htaccess-File) for geting infos about the permalinks

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 <FilesMatch "\.(htm|php|js|css|htc|png|gif|jpe?g|ico|xml|csv|txt|swf|flv|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf|gz)$">
RewriteEngine Off
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?catslugs=$0 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately the 301-Redirekt doesnt work. What ist wrong, any tips?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QUERY_STRING` cannot be matched using `Redirect` directive. You need to use `RewriteCond` in mod_rewrite. Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)DH=35(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.asp$ http://www.domain.ch/karriere? [L,NC,R=301]

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|php|js|css|htc|png|gif|jpe?g|ico|xml|csv|txt|swf|flv|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf|gz)$">
RewriteEngine Off
</FilesMatch>


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?catslugs=$0 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. It works perfect. But another questions, for SEO or for google, is this the same as 301 permanent redirection?

Comment: sorry, just see inside the code that information. time to go sleeping;-)